# Was that creature a Bilgesnipe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

Late in the film *Thor: The Dark World*, we see a large creature on Jotunheim (possibly the same species as the extremely large creature that Thor killed on Jotunheim in *Thor*?).  It's large, and has horns.

In *Avengers*, Thor describes a fictional creature, the Bilgesnipe:

> Thor: We on Asgard pretend that we are more advanced, but we, we come here battling like Bilgesnipe.
>
> Agent Coulson: Like what?
>
> Thor: The Bilgesnipe, you know; huge, scaly, big antlers. You don't have those?
>
> Agent Coulson: Don't think so.
>
> Thor: They are repulsive, and they trample everything in their path.

Was this creature a Bilgesnipe?  It at least partially matches the description from *Avengers*.

**Note**: I'm looking for information from the Marvel Cinematic Universe's canon.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: @DVK No, I don't have a screenshot of a movie that just opened in theaters.

Comment: Youtube would usually have a clip or two.

Comment: I always thought it was a combination of two terms for naval engineering.  The bilge is the hollow portion of the bottom of the inside of a ship, and a Snipe is a somewhat derogatory term for people who work on the engines.

Comment: @Keen: I'm fairly sure it was the same monster as in *Thor*. Pictures from the first film are here; is this what you mean? http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Jotunheim_Beast << And according to that, this Beast is native to Jotunheim, whereas the Bilgesnipe is native to Asgard. I can’t find a citation for that, though.

Comment: @Keen IIRC, the creature is in the trailer

Comment: @Izkata - I just checked and didn't see: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npvJ9FTgZbM

Comment: @DVK Huh, nevermind then.  I somehow managed to avoid the trailer until yesterday, then saw the movie today.  Must've merged them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a Bilgesnipe. In the Empire [spoiler podcast](http://www.empireonline.com/news/story.asp?NID=39340) for The Dark World with Kevin Feige (producer) and Alan Taylor (director), one of the Empire journalists asks this very question (at about 14:37). Alan Taylor confirms it to be a smaller (potentially baby) version of the creature from the first film.

Answer (score 7):

I think that this may be a picture of the beast (Thor's pet, natch) from the "[Avengers: Assemble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_Assemble_%28TV_series%29)" TV series, but I don't have a complete proof of that yet (the fact that there's a DisneyXD logo on it makes it seem authentic):

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's a Bilgesnipe from the *Avengers Assemble* cartoon.